# how to add OriginalFilename and commit hash fields into a Electron app executable?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I would like to add OriginalFilename and git commit hash into my Electron app details( for windows os ).

1. I explored app-builder-lib(https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/master/packages/app-builder-lib) - part of electron-builder package sources and OriginalFilename is setting up to empty string there. Possibility to add custom field I didn't find too.
2. I explored cli of electron-packager, https://github.com/electron/electron-packager/blob/master/usage.txt but I also din't find smt about custom field adding(but add OriginalFilename field is possible).

How I can resolve this issue?
How can I add commit info or some custom field to a exe file properties?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: OriginalFilename used from app-builder-lib, commit hash decided to ignore)